# automatically update age

Tags: html

I got a website with an about section. there is some text about me including my current age. Lazy as I am I don't want to change that date after every birthday.

Is there an easy script to display my age based on my birthdate? I didn't find anything like that on the web.

Thx ahead.

Comment: Apart from the fact that its a bad question, "I didn't find anything like that on the web." is very unlikely!
But here is a little help: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/228987/Calculate-Age-from-Date-of-birth-using-Javscript-o

Comment: there's nothing like a bad question, only bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript. This should be more than enough to get you started..

```js
// The date you were born
var birthDate = new Date(1990, 6, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// The current date
var currentDate = new Date();

// The age in years
var age = currentDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

// Compare the months
var month = currentDate.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

// Compare the days
var day = currentDate.getDate() - birthDate.getDate();

// If the date has already happened this year
if ( month < 0 || month == 0 && day < 0 )
{
    age--;
}

alert( age );
```